# How to name method

Tags: javascript, refactoring, naming

I am very sorry to ask this philosophical question, but I have a very long argument with colleague.
There is a metho:d

```
function GetInterval(){ return someSimpleObj;}
```

Requirements changed that this method could return empty result. I mean when no data is found. After a long argument about returning null or exception, which should be handled in outer scope, we decided to return null.

However I propose to change signature of method to

```
function GetIntervalOrNull()
```

After that started another argument that throwing nulls is obvious behaviour for functions and it is no need to rename it. However, I believe that returning nulls without warning is a lack of design and it is not usual to return nulls.
So questions are:

1. Is it usual behaviour to return null for function?
2. How function which return nulls should be named?
3. Do you know libraries which have GetSmthOrNull? And for which libraries throwing null is ok behaviour and for which is not.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How about you guys stop arguing and start coding instead. What the method returns or what it's named doesn't really matter as long as it does what it's supposed to, and I'd be more concerned with you guys not using camelCase than the name of the functions !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it usual behaviour to return null for function?

If it's not an exceptional condition, yes, it's entirely normal. Consider DOM's `getElementById`, for instance, which returns `null` if there is no matching element, which isn't exceptional and therefore doesn't warrant an exception. Or JavaScript's own [`String#match`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.10), which returns `null` if the string doesn't contain any matches for the regex.

> How function which return nulls should be named?

This is opinion-based. Normally, though, there's nothing special about it; see examples above.

> Do you know libraries which have GetSmthOrNull?

I haven't run into any, no.